# WinDbg: Debug outputs missing when debugging via USB Debug Cable

Tags: windbg

This is the first time I try to debug a Windows 7 x86_32 target via a USB Debug cable. In thanks to the author of [this](https://www.apriorit.com/dev-blog/210-win-debug-with-usb) article I successful set up host and target for a debugging connection.

Unfortunately I had to find out that there is something different, compared to debuggin via serial cable: My application produces debug messages via OutputDebugString(), and I can see them when using the serial debug connection. But if I use the USB debug connection, the messages are missing.

I have no idea what has gone wrong. Is there something special I have to set up or take care about?